# onFocusChange Doesnt respond from within a view pager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, onfocus, pagerslidingtabstrip

Reposting this as I initially posted it originally with the wrong title and so it got lost in the void of questions.

I'm creating a small timetable app, and am currently creating a screen with some tabs. Each tab is a seperate fragment and each have 20 edit texts inside of them. What I aim to do, is if the user types in one of the edit texts, then clicks off of it and the focus is lost, to send the text from the edit text field to the main activity. Then, when the confirm button is clicked, any text that is in the edit texts is then saved to an SQLite database. 
My problem is that the focus listener doesn't seem to be working. 
Here is one of the fragment's code:

```
package com.example.schoolandrevisiontimetable;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;



public class Input_slessontime_monday extends Fragment implements OnFocusChangeListener{

    OnMondayEditTextChangedListener monCallback;


    private String mondayString;
    private int mondayPeriod;
    private int mondayPosition;

     public void MondayEditTextChanged(String mondayEditText, int period, int position){
         mondayString = mondayEditText;
         mondayPeriod = period;
         mondayPosition=position;

         monCallback.onMondayEditTextChanged(mondayString, mondayPeriod, mondayPosition);
     }


    public interface OnMondayEditTextChangedListener {
        public void onMondayEditTextChanged(String mondayEditText, int period, int position);
    }




    EditText[][] mondayInput   = new EditText[11][2];
    String  [][] mondayStrings = new String  [11][2];




    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_input_slessontime_monday,
                container, false);

        mondayInput[1][0] = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mondayslesson1start);
        mondayInput[1][1]  = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mondayslesson1end);

        mondayInput[2][0] = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mondayslesson2start);
        mondayInput[2][1]   = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mondayslesson2end);

...

//this continues up to 10. Had to delete the rest due to character limitations

        Log.v("Monday", "Edit texts all set");



        return rootView;    
    }

     @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);

            // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
            // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
            try {
                monCallback = (OnMondayEditTextChangedListener) activity;
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                        + " must implement OnMondayEditTextChanged");
            }
        }

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        Log.v("monday", "focus change!");
        String edittext;
    if(!hasFocus)   
        switch(v.getId()){

        case R.id.mondayslesson1start:
            edittext = mondayInput[1][0].getText().toString();
            MondayEditTextChanged(edittext,1,0);
        break;
        case R.id.mondayslesson1end:
            edittext = mondayInput[1][1].getText().toString();
            MondayEditTextChanged(edittext,1,1);
        break;

        case R.id.mondayslesson2start:
            edittext = mondayInput[2][0].getText().toString();
            MondayEditTextChanged(edittext,2,0);
        break;
        case R.id.mondayslesson2end:
            edittext = mondayInput[2][1].getText().toString();
            MondayEditTextChanged(edittext,2,1);
        break;

         //this continues up to 10. Had to delete the rest due to character limitations

    }


    }


}
```

Here is the activity's code:

```
package com.example.schoolandrevisiontimetable;


import java.util.List;

import com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip;
import Database.DatabaseHelper;
import Database.MC_sschoolday;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;


/**DETECTIVEREPORT:
 * onfocuschange does nothing
 * but it seems that getCount() is called everytime you click onto another textbox, or scroll. probably unrelated.
 * **/


public class Input_slessontime extends FragmentActivity implements 
Input_slessontime_monday.OnMondayEditTextChangedListener,
Input_slessontime_tuesday.OnTuesdayEditTextChangedListener,
Input_slessontime_wednesday.OnWednesdayEditTextChangedListener{

    //this class uses the pagerslidingtabstrip library from https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip to create a tab layout.

    MC_sschoolday[] sday = new MC_sschoolday[7];  //new array of schooldays

    int amountOfDays;

    List<MC_sschoolday> schoolday;

    DatabaseHelper db;
    public static FragmentManager fgmanger;

    private PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs;
    private ViewPager pager;
    private MyPagerAdapter adapter;

    Input_slessontime_monday mondayFragment;

    String[][][] slessonTimes = new String[8][11][2];
    int numberOfLessonTimes=0;
    String[] slessonPointer = new String[140];



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.v("LessonTimeInput", "oncreate");

        db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_input_slessontime);
        fgmanger = getSupportFragmentManager();
        schoolday = db.getAllSSchoolDays();
        amountOfDays = getAmountOfDaysUsed();

        tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip)findViewById(R.id.tabs); //set the tabs
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager); //set the pager
        adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(fgmanger); //set the adapter

        pager.setAdapter(adapter); //set the adapter to the pager

        final int pageMargin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 4, getResources()
                .getDisplayMetrics());
        pager.setPageMargin(pageMargin);

        tabs.setViewPager(pager); 





        db.close();

    }


    @Override
    public void onMondayEditTextChanged(String mondayEditText, int period, int position) {
        slessonTimes[1][period][position] = mondayEditText;
        Log.v("LessonTimeInput", "MondayLessontime Added "+ period + " " + position);
        slessonPointer[numberOfLessonTimes] = ("1"+period+position);
        numberOfLessonTimes++;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTuesdayEditTextChanged(String tuesdayEditText, int period,
            int position) {
        Log.v("LessonTimeInput", "TuesdayLessontime Added "+ period + " " + position);
        slessonTimes[2][period][position] = tuesdayEditText;
        slessonPointer[numberOfLessonTimes] = ("2"+period+position);
        numberOfLessonTimes++;

    }

    @Override
    public void onWednesdayEditTextChanged(String wednesdayEditText, int period,
            int position) {
        Log.v("LessonTimeInput", "TuesdayLessontime Added "+ period + " " + position);
        slessonTimes[3][period][position] = wednesdayEditText;
        slessonPointer[numberOfLessonTimes] = ("3"+period+position);
        numberOfLessonTimes++;

    }

    public void confirmslesson(View v){

            }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.input_slessontime, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */


    //this gets the amount of days used, so that the code knows how many tabs to generate
public int getAmountOfDaysUsed(){
    db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());   //open the database

    int amountOfDaysUsed=0; //initialise this int   

    for (int i =0; i<7; i++){
        sday[i]=schoolday.get(i); //stores the lessons in an array

     }

    for (int i =0; i<7; i++){
        if(sday[i].getUsed().toString().equals("y")){ //find how many days are used
            amountOfDaysUsed++; 
        }
    } 

    db.close(); //close the database

    Log.v("LessonTimeInput", "amount of days used " + amountOfDaysUsed);
    return amountOfDaysUsed;  //return the int
}

//small subclass for the pageradapter

public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {



    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {     
        super(fm);
    }



    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        String[] days = new String[7];
        db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());   


        int usedCount2=0;

        for (int i =0; i< 7; i++){

            sday[i]=schoolday.get(i);

                if(sday[i].getUsed().toString().equals("y")){
                    days[usedCount2] = sday[i].getschool_day();

                    usedCount2++;

                }

        }       

        db.close();


        Log.v("LessonTimeInput", "getPageTitle");
        return days[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        Log.v("LessonTimeInput", "getCount");
        return getAmountOfDaysUsed();
    }



    public Fragment switchFragmentDay(int num) {
        DatabaseHelper db;
        db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());   
        MC_sschoolday[] sday = new MC_sschoolday[7];

        int usedCount1=amountOfDays;

        int [] dayID = new int[usedCount1];         


        int usedCount2=0;
        for (int i =0; i< amountOfDays; i++){
            sday[i]=schoolday.get(i);
            if(sday[i].getUsed().toString().equals("y")){
                dayID[usedCount2] = (int) sday[i].getSchool_day_id();
                usedCount2++;
            }
        }
        db.close();
        switch (dayID[num]){
        case 1:
            return new Input_slessontime_monday();
        case 2:
            return new Input_slessontime_tuesday();
        case 3:
            return new Input_slessontime_wednesday();
        case 4:
            return new Input_slessontime_thursday();
        case 5:
            return new Input_slessontime_friday();
        case 6:
            return new Input_slessontime_saturday();
        case 7:
            return new Input_slessontime_sunday();
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position){              
        case 0:
            return switchFragmentDay(0);
        case 1:
            return switchFragmentDay(1);
        case 2:
            return switchFragmentDay(2);
        case 3:
            return switchFragmentDay(3);
        case 4:
            return switchFragmentDay(4);
        case 5:
            return switchFragmentDay(5);
        case 6:
            return switchFragmentDay(6);

        }

    return null;
    }

}

public void StartIntent(Class<?> intentclass) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, intentclass);            
    startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

The XML for the fragment:

```
 <ScrollView 
 android:id="@+id/monday_fragment"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 tools:context="com.pipturner.timetable.Input_slessontime_monday"

 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" >

 <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


       <CheckBox
           android:id="@+id/mondayslesson1used"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="80dp"
           android:text="@string/prompt_lesson" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mondayslesson1start"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:hint="@string/start"
            android:dependency="mondayslesson1used"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:ems="10" />

       <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mondayslesson1end"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:hint="@string/end"
            android:dependency="mondayslesson2used"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:ems="10" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


       <CheckBox
           android:id="@+id/mondayslesson2used"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="80dp"
           android:text="@string/prompt_lesson" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mondayslesson2start"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
             android:hint="@string/start"
            android:dependency="mondayslesson1used"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:ems="10" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mondayslesson2end"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:hint="@string/end"
            android:dependency="mondayslesson2used"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:ems="10" />
        </LinearLayout>


 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

       <CheckBox
           android:id="@+id/mondayslesson3used"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="80dp"
           android:text="@string/prompt_lesson" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mondayslesson3start"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
             android:hint="@string/start"
            android:dependency="mondayslesson3used"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:ems="10" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mondayslesson3end"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:hint="@string/end"
            android:dependency="mondayslesson3used"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:ems="10" />
        </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

       <CheckBox
           android:id="@+id/mondayslesson4used"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="80dp"
           android:text="@string/prompt_lesson" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mondayslesson4start"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
             android:hint="@string/start"
            android:dependency="mondayslesson4used"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:ems="10" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mondayslesson4end"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:hint="@string/end"
            android:dependency="mondayslesson4used"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:ems="10" />
        </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

       <CheckBox
           android:id="@+id/mondayslesson5used"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="80dp"
           android:text="@string/prompt_lesson" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mondayslesson5start"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
             android:hint="@string/start"
            android:dependency="mondayslesson5used"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:ems="10" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mondayslesson5end"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:hint="@string/end"
            android:dependency="mondayslesson5used"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:ems="10" />
        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

       <CheckBox
           android:id="@+id/mondayslesson6used"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="80dp"
           android:text="@string/prompt_lesson" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mondayslesson6start"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
             android:hint="@string/start"
            android:dependency="mondayslesson6used"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:ems="10" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mondayslesson6end"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:hint="@string/end"
            android:dependency="mondayslesson6used"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:ems="10" />
        </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

       <CheckBox
           android:id="@+id/mondayslesson7used"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="80dp"
           android:text="@string/prompt_lesson" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mondayslesson7start"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
             android:hint="@string/start"
            android:dependency="mondayslesson7used"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:ems="10" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mondayslesson7end"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:hint="@string/end"
            android:dependency="mondayslesson7used"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:ems="10" />
        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

       <CheckBox
           android:id="@+id/mondayslesson8used"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="80dp"
           android:text="@string/prompt_lesson" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mondayslesson8start"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
             android:hint="@string/start"
            android:dependency="mondayslesson8used"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:ems="10" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mondayslesson8end"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:hint="@string/end"
            android:dependency="mondayslesson8used"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:ems="10" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

       <CheckBox
           android:id="@+id/mondayslesson9used"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="80dp"
           android:text="@string/prompt_lesson" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mondayslesson9start"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
             android:hint="@string/start"
            android:dependency="mondayslesson9used"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:ems="10" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mondayslesson9end"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:hint="@string/end"
            android:dependency="mondayslesson9used"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:ems="10" />
        </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

       <CheckBox
           android:id="@+id/mondayslesson10used"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="80dp"
           android:text="@string/prompt_lesson" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mondayslesson10start"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
             android:hint="@string/start"
            android:dependency="mondayslesson10used"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:ems="10" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mondayslesson10end"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:hint="@string/end"
            android:dependency="mondayslesson10used"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:ems="10" />
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

and the XML for the activity:

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:background="@drawable/background_tabs" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:context=".Input_slessontime" />


      <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:id="@+id/cancelslessontime"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:text="@string/cancel"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:id="@+id/confirmslessontime"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:text="@string/confirm"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="confirmslesson" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Something that may be related, is that when I click on or off an edit text, or scroll the fragment, getCount() is called. Probably unrelated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

needed to set an onFocusListener.
//Thanks for the help guys//
¬¬